# Panel regression in R with variable coefficients

Tags: r, panel-data, coefficients, plm

We have tried to do two (similar) panel regressions in R.

1) One with time and individual fixed effects (the usual intercept dummies) using plm(). However, we are only interested mostly interested in a "slope coefficient" or beta for each individual and not one for all of the individuals:

[Regression 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iwBV.png)

Where alpha_i is the individual fixed effect, gamme_t is the time fixed effect. The sum of X is the variable X and three lags:

[Sum X variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7ASv.png)

We have already included the lagged X variables as new columns in our dataset so in our specification in the code we simply treat them as four different variables:
This is an attempt at using plm() and include our own dummy variables for each individual Beta

```
plm(income ~ (factor(firmid)-1)*(expense_rate + lag1 + lag2 + lag3), data = data1,
effect = c("time"), model = c("within"), index = c("name", "date"))
```

The lag1, lag,2, lag2 are the lagged variables of expense rate.
Data1 is in the form of a data frame.
“(factor(firmid)-1)” is an attempt at introducing dummies to get Betas for each individual instead of one for all individuals.

2) The second (and simpler) regression is:
[Regression 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXZfy.png)

This is an example of our attempt at using pvcm

```
pvcm1 <- pvcm(income ~ expense_rate + lag1 + lag2 + lag3, data = data1,
          effect = "individual", model = "within")
```

Our question is what specific code and or packages/functions which would be suitable for these regressions. We have tried pvcm to no avail, running into errors such as:
“Error in table(index[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iwBV.png)], index[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7ASv.png)], useNA = "ifany") : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements”
and
“Error: cannot allocate vector of size 599.7 Gb”

. Furthermore, pvcm() does not seem to be able to cope with both individua and time fixed effects as in 1).

Comment: for your first question `plm::fixef(model)` will give you the individual fixed effect of each entity

Comment: We are more interested in the individual slope/beta coefficient rather than the intercept coefficient.

Comment: but you are estimating a fixed-effects model? don't you want a random effects model to allow the slope to vary by entity?

Comment: Sorry I had to look up random effects model to double check. No we want a fixed effects model but we are interested in a B with individual index (or one beta for each individual) rather than a beta for the whole sample. Look carefully at the pictures, the Beta is indexed with i for individual and the tau which has to do with the lag and not time - see picture two.

Comment: About 2): Did you set the `index` argument of `pvcm` or is `data1` a pdata.frame?